# gnuplot and octave: a distribution curve with a skew

Tags: gnuplot, octave

I am trying to plot some distribution curves, and I have obtained the following using `octave`:

- mean
- median
- standard deviation
- variance
- skewness

AFAIK and after long hours of searching the internets, I only found examples for the normal/Gaussian distribution curve:

```
std=0.1674766919608221
mean=0.6058016666666665
normal(x, mu, sd) = (1/(sd*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sd**2))
plot normal(x,mean,std) with lines
```

which draws a nice curve.
However, I am trying to draw a skewed one, judging by the difference of the mean, median and skewness, such as the ones [shown here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/skewness.html).

How can I draw in gnuplot such a curve?
The gnuplot example shows something very similar [at the bottom example](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/random.html) but they don't explain how they draw/plot it.

**EDIT**

In order to calculate the actual function and find its parameters, I've asked in [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595119/how-can-i-draw-the-skewed-normal-distribution-curve) where I got a thorough reply.
I realise now that this is two questions, but it appears that what I need, is to use `octave` to obtain the PDF of my data, and then obtain the CDF.
Cristoph's Wikipedia link to [skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) suggests that what I need is:

```
f(x) = 2*stdnormal_pdf(x)*stdnormal_cdf(a*x)
```

Of course I could be wrong.
Obtaining *alpha* which is the shape is unclear (my [math post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1595119/how-can-i-draw-the-skewed-normal-distribution-curve) suggests using solving for *delta* first and then for *alpha* which seems very complicated for me). 
I'm willing to bet there is a function in `octave` which eludes me that does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Skew normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) for the function definition. You can then plot the probability density function of the skew-normal distribution with

```
normal(x) = 1.0 / sqrt(2*pi) * exp(-(x**2)/2.0)
cdf(x) = 0.5 * (1 + erf(x / sqrt(2)))
skewed_normal(x, x0, sigma, alpha) = (2.0 / sigma) * normal((x - x0) / sigma) * cdf(alpha * (x - x0) / sigma)

set xrange [-4:4]
plot skewed_normal(x, 0, 1, -4) title 'α = -4',\
     skewed_normal(x, 0, 1, -1) title 'α = -1',\
     skewed_normal(x, 0, 1, 0) title 'α = 0',\
     skewed_normal(x, 0, 1, 1) title 'α = 1',\
     skewed_normal(x, 0, 1, 4) title 'α = 4'
```

[image]

Comment: hi, many thanks for the answer. I asked in math.stackexchange how to calculate the actual formula.
My guess is that I only need to calculate my sigma and alpha for my data, and then use the function you've defined?